# Can you specify on which core should a batch script run?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, batch

I have a batch script that runs a program for a while. The program is monothread. I would like to run several instances of this program in parallel and be sure they do not run using the same core/thread.

The reason for that is that I am measuring the time it takes to run the program and I would like to try and avoid having biased results because some instances running using concurrent cpu ressources.

Is there a way to specify in my batch script a given core/thread number and avoid the aforementioned bias I could get ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try running it with the `taskset` utility with the -c option like `taskset -c 0 batch.job`. In order to find your cpu-count you can use the `nproc` tool.

[article about process affinity - linux](https://www.glennklockwood.com/hpc-howtos/process-affinity.html)

[taskset manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset)

**Edit:** On windows you can probably use the similar `start` utility with the `/affinity` option. 
[processor affinity in windows/linux](https://binkurt.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-change-processor-affinity-in.html)

Comment: Well I am on windows, I didn't specify it in the text but in the tags. Looking up taskset there might be a solution [on this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829974/taskset-equivalent-in-windows).

Comment: Looks like on windows your best bet would be the `start`-command with the `/affinity`-option. Sorry I can't help much further as I am more of a Linux-Guy ; )

Comment: I tried that but it looks like every 5 seconds or so, the process switches thread. I will update if I find the reason.

Comment: It works fine ! The problem was that I was using a batch script to run a batch script to run the program. So I guess the second batch script was indeed running on a given core, but the program it was running was not. You need to use start command with /affinity option when running the .exe, if you do that on the .bat, it doesn't echoes onto the "child" processes.

Comment: Well now it looks like `/affinity` does echo onto the "child" processes... I'm confused. But it's still working !

Comment: @juo - Instead of a comment clarifying your answer, can you edit your answer, and gear it specifically towards Windows?  You should also quote any reference material, in the instances, where people are unable to visit the reference website themselfs.